# How to prevent touch when clicking on the background of the Android dialog

Tags: java, android, kotlin

If we click the background of the dialog and click the back key, the dialog will not be canceled.

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
setCancelable(false);
```

However, while the dialog is not canceled, there is a phenomenon that the click in the background in the buttons and the check box are clicked.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear!!

Comment: From your comment, your issue is when you open your dialog, the background (current activity) components are still clickable, right? Try to wrap all of them with a `RelativeLayout` and when you open the dialog call `wrapper.setEnabled(false)` when the dialog is dismissed, call `wrapper.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
 I solved it by putting this sentence in.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in onCreate method:

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: This code does not close the dialog, but the check box or button in the background is still clicked.

Comment: my bad, actually this is weird, can you  provide the code in your main activity/fragments.

Comment: if the dialog  is in  activity or fragment, when the Alert dialog is popped up on screen, Activity/fragment  will be onPuase() state the buttons should not be clickable till the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
 I solved it by putting this sentence in.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: great, thank you for sharing the solution, I would suggest you to add this answer in the answer section, maybe it will help someone, cheers lad!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first line keep only `dialog.setCancelable(false);`

Comment: I think that sentence is a code that cannot be canceled when the back key is used. What I want is to block the click of a check box or button on the background of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to prevent background touch such as dialogues.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Use this code to make the background touch impossible.

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Thank you for your answers. Have a nice day!